# Should I call api from node (server side) or in react (client side)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server-side, client-side, mern

I have tried to call api from a govt website to get the covid vaccine available in that pincode. I created a function with api call in a file named **searchbypinapi.js** and imported and used the function in **Pindiv.jsx**.  **(I am posting the Code of both the file)**

**searchbypinapi.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const Searchbypinapi = (pincode) => {
    
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
    var nDate = date.slice(8, 10) + '-' + date.slice(5, 7) + '-' + date.slice(0, 4);
    let pincodeconfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByPin?pincode=' + pincode +'&date=' + nDate ,
        headers: {
            'accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'hi_IN',
            'User-Agent': 'covid19'
        }
      };
      axios(pincodeconfig)
          .then((response) => {
            return(response.data);
          })
          .catch(error => {
              return error;
          });

      
      
};

export default Searchbypinapi;
```

**Pindiv.jsx**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Searchbypinapi from '../../api/searchbypinapi';

const Pindiv = () => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState("");

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        Searchbypinapi(input)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            });
    }

    return (
        <div id="pincode" className="pinsearch d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="example">
                    <input type="text" autoComplete="off" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search.." name="search" />
                    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>

            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Pindiv
```

When I called the api in react it is giving error :-

[click here to see the error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4olS.png)

But when I run the same api in nodejs, it console.log() the data successfully.

I was confused as it is not running in reactjs. Please suggest me any solution of this or I should create a server folder to create api request and than send it to client side with axios.

**Note :- I have also used other api's like (https://api.covid19india.org/data.json) they are running perfectly, only this api is not running.**

Answer (score 0):

Your request is blocked because of CORS (cross-origin request sharing).

The 3th party server (`co-vin.in` in this case) determines the origins (other websites) than can access the server. Apparently your website is not allowed.

However, CORS is *enforced by the browser*. That is why your request does not work from the browser (your React app) but is does work from your server.

As a solution, you can proxy the request through your server, as you already suggested.